# Can I use a 29er rigid front fork and still use 650b wheels (brakes are disc)? Any negative side effects?

Tags: fork

I have a Jamis Dragon 27.5 hardtail that I would like to convert to more of a gravel bike. It is hard to find a 27.5 rigid fork with a 1-1/8" non-tapered steer tube. Would there be any negative effects to using a 700c fork instead with 650b wheels? The brakes are disc (160, 140).

Comment: This is quite a common combination. 650b wheels are often put on gravel bikes that are designed for 700c. However, as the frame was made for a different fork, wouldn't you change the slope of the whole bike?

Comment: @VladimirF Not if the replacement fork has a similar offset and axle to crown dimension as the original fork (with a normal amount of sag). Rigid mtbs used to be sold with suspension corrected forks (they still are, e.g. Trek 1120, but rigid mtb doesn’t seem to be as common these days)so that a suspension fork with an appropriate amount of travel could be installed without messing up the handling of the bike.

Answer (score 3):

With disk brakes you can easily run 650B in a 29er fork.

The main consideration is maintaining the bikes geometry. You should look for a 29 fork with the offset and a crown to axle measurement as close as possible to the original.

As you are changing to no suspension travel, remove the sag from the original forks measurements (typically 20%, 25mm for a 120).   From specs the fork you have has a 504mm axle-crown, less 25mm sag, you want a 29er rigid with about 480mm axle crown. (You do need to confirm these numbers by measuring your fork.)